# Prove by induction that the sum of the terms in a sequence is: $\frac{a_0 - a_{n+1} }{1 - r} $

Tags: sequences-and-series, number-theory, discrete-mathematics, induction, proof-explanation

I am trying to prove the following by induction.

Let the follownig finite sequence $ a_0, a_1, a_2, a_3,....,a_n $ be defined by the rule:
$$ a_i = a_0  \cdot  r^i$$ where r is some number not equal to 1.

Prove by induction that the sum of the terms in the sequence is 
$$ \frac{a_0-a_{n+1}}{1 - r}$$
$ a_{n+1} $ is defined by the sequence, even though it is not part of the sequence.

I am completely lost on how to approached this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that for $n=1$ we have
$$
a_{0} + a_{1} = a_{0}(1+r) = a_{0}\frac{1-r^{2}}{1-r} = \frac{a_{0} - a_{o}r^{2}}{1-r} = \frac{a_{0} - a_{2}}{1-r}.
$$
If $n \geq 1$ is an integer such that
$$
\sum_{i=1}^{n-1}{a_{i}} = \frac{a_{0} - a_{n}}{1-r},
$$
then 
$$
\sum_{i=1}^{n}a_{i} = \frac{a_{0}-a_{n}}{1-r} + a_{n} = \frac{a_{0}-a_{n} + a_{n} - ra_{n}}{1-r} = \frac{a_{0} - ra_{n}}{1-r} = \frac{a_{0} - a_{n+1}}{1-r}.
$$

Comment: @EricClaption How did you go from  
How did you go from $ \frac { a_{ 0 }-a_{ n+1 } }{ 1-r } + a_{n+1} = \frac{a_0 - a_{n+1} + a_{n+1} - ra_{n+1}}{1-r}$

Comment: Yeah it is just $\frac{y}{x} + z = \frac{y + xz}{x}$.

Answer (score 1):

Let ${ S }_{ n }=\frac { a_{ 0 }-a_{ n+1 } }{ 1-r } $ we should show that $${ S }_{ n+1 }=\frac { a_{ 0 }-a_{ n+2 } }{ 1-r } $$
$$\underset { { S }_{ n } }{ \underbrace { { a }_{ 0 }+{ a }_{ 1 }+...+{ a }_{ n } }  } +{ a }_{ n+1 }=\frac { a_{ 0 }-a_{ n+1 } }{ 1-r } +{ a }_{ n+1 }=\frac { a_{ 0 }-a_{ n+1 }+{ a }_{ n+1 }-r{ a }_{ n+1 } }{ 1-r } =\frac { { a }_{ 0 }-r{ a }_{ n+1 } }{ 1-r } =\frac { { a }_{ 0 }-{ a }_{ n+2 } }{ 1-r } $$

Comment: How did you go from $ \frac { a_{ 0 }-a_{ n+1 } }{ 1-r } + a_{n+1} = \frac{a_0 - a_{n+1} + a_{n+1} - ra_{n+1}}{1-r} $

Comment: it is an addition of fractions

Answer (score 0):

For $n+1$ you have:

$$a_0+a_1+...+a_n+a_{n+1}=\frac{a_0-a_{n+1}}{1-r}+a_{n+1}=\\
\frac{a_0-a_{n+1}+(1-r)a_{n+1}}{1-r}=\frac{a_0-ra_{n+1}}{1-r}=\frac{a_0-a_{n+2}}{1-r}$$

For the last equality we used that

$$ra_{n+1}=ra_0r^{n+1}=a_0r^{n+2}=a_{n+2}$$